# Unable to forward/map port internaly in Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port

I am currently having an app with 3 different databases (it's for a test). I have the following docker image:

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.15

WORKDIR /myapp

# Download wait for it tool. 
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it
```

and the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: sh -c "/wait-for-it postgres:10001 -- /wait-for-it oracle:10000 -- /wait-for-it mongodb:10002"
    depends_on:
      - oracle
      - mongodb
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  oracle:
    image: chameleon82/oracle-xe-10g:latest
    ports:
      - "10000:8080"
    expose:
      - 10000
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    ports:
      - "10001:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_DB=testdb
    expose:
      - 10001
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "10002:27017"
    expose:
      - 10002
```

The thing is, as you saw, my app listens on 8080, but so Oracle does. I know I can change my app port, but still, I would like to switch Oracle to another port. I am trying to achieve it from port mapping, but I do feel that it only works for the host machine, not for a use from within the docker-compose, am I wrong?

Comment: Any specific reason to change any of those two ports from 8080 to something else? You can have as may containers you want, all listening on 8080 without any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of services within a Docker Compose network (i.e. `app`, `oracle`) as distinct hosts. Each is addressable by its service name, i.e. `app` should refer to the `oracle` service by this name (`oracle`).

The port mapping allows you to expose (and map) service ports within a Docker Compose network to (possibly different) host ports. This is commonly because, the host has a singular dimension of port spaces (0...65535) whereas **each** service within the Docker Compose network has a port space. 2 services (e.g. `http1` and `http2`) may each use port e.g. `8080` but there's only one `8080` on the host and so, to expose each of these services on your host, one would have to yield; one could also be on the host's `8080` but the other would need to be elsewhere, perhaps `8081`.

In your case, e.g. `oracle` runs on `8080` within the Docker Compose network and is exposed on the host's port `10000`. As far as the `app` service is concerned, this service is available as `oracle:8080` (`8080` not `10000`) within the Docker Compose network.

The `expose` syntax is purely documentary and has no functional effect.

#### Responding to comments

If I run your Compose script as-is, it does not work. This is expected because e.g. `postgres` is available on `5432` within the Compose network not on `10001`

```sh
docker-compose logs app
Attaching to 63690852_app_1
app_1       | wait-for-it: waiting 15 seconds for postgres:10001
app_1       | wait-for-it: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for postgres:10001
app_1       | wait-for-it: waiting 15 seconds for oracle:10000
app_1       | wait-for-it: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for oracle:10000
app_1       | wait-for-it: waiting 15 seconds for mongodb:10002
app_1       | wait-for-it: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for mongodb:10002
```

If I correct the ports:

```
command: sh -c "/wait-for-it postgres:5432 -- /wait-for-it oracle:8080 -- /wait-for-it mongodb:27017"
```

It works as expected:

```sh
docker-compose logs app
Attaching to 63690852_app_1
app_1       | wait-for-it: waiting 15 seconds for postgres:5432
app_1       | wait-for-it: postgres:5432 is available after 0 seconds
app_1       | wait-for-it: waiting 15 seconds for oracle:8080
app_1       | wait-for-it: oracle:8080 is available after 8 seconds
app_1       | wait-for-it: waiting 15 seconds for mongodb:27017
app_1       | wait-for-it: mongodb:27017 is available after 0 seconds
```

Comment: Hey! that’s weird because on my end it doesn’t work.. you can try you will see that it works only on 5432 for Postgres by example.. trying from 10001 ain’t working for me (Ubuntu 20.04). Do you think it could be related to wait-for-it?

Comment: It may be. I'm unfamiliar with `wait-for-it` but assume it's a script that periodically pings the database endpoint. You can test this using the Adminer container and pointing it to each of your database instances within the Compose network.

Comment: I updated the answer with an explanation of what I mean. It works for me.

Comment: Wow alright thanks, what a good answer :) Appreciate!